# How to make code wait to complete fileReader.onload() thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var error = "" ;
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = e.target.result;
  image.onload = function () {
    var megaPixels = ( this.height * this.width ) / 1000000;
    console.log(megaPixels);
    if(megaPixels >= 4){
      error = "d-none" ;
      console.log(">= than 4");
    }
  }
  console.log("error: "+error);
}
```

`console.log("error: "+error);` should get executed at the end of external onload but it gets executed before the other logs present above in the code.

OUTPUT:

```
upload.php:98            error:
upload.php:91            24.160256
upload.php:94            >= than 4
```

Comment: you put code inside the callback - javascript doesn't "wait"

Comment: Can you mention the part I should put in callback?

Comment: the part that needs to be there `console.log("error: "+error);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript Promises to achieve this efficiently

```
error='';
let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject)
{
    reader.onload = function(e)
    {
       
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = e.target.result;
        image.onload = function ()
        {
            var megaPixels = ( this.height * this.width ) / 1000000;
            console.log(megaPixels);
            if(megaPixels >= 4)
            {
                error = "d-none" ;
                console.log(">= than 4");
            }
        }
    }
    myResolve();
});
myPromise.then(
    function(value)
    {
        console.log("error: "+error);
        /* code if successful */
    },
    function(error)
    {
        /* code if some error */
    }
);
```